# what does "by" mean in this context?

Tags: prepositions

By 18 January 2016, Member States shall notify to
the Commission the list of professions for which a prior
check of qualifications is necessary under Article 7(4).

Sometimes I get confused when it comes to "by" and a date..
Does this mean that "the Member States shall notify to the Commission the list before 18 January 2016", or "starting from 18 January 2016", like, "after 18 January 2016"? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

'By' in that sentence means that "the Member States shall notify to the Commission the list before 18 January 2016". The sentence has the word "shall" in it, which indicates that they will before the 18 January.